# Batch Copy and run acting strange

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that needs to copy my EXE to desktop and run it from there.

Code:

```
copy client.exe %USERPROFILE%\Desktop
%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\client.exe
```

What seems to happen is that client.exe is indeed copied to desktop and ran but acts as if it is in the directory of the original client.exe

Comment: How can you difference it, and why you must running it from desktop?

Comment: I got to task manager, select the process>properties and I can see where the file is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that as far as the batch is concerned, the current directory is wherever the batch is execute from.

If you want the current directory to be the desktop, you'd need to explicitly set it

```
copy client.exe %USERPROFILE%\Desktop
pushd "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop"
client.exe 
popd
```

or

```
copy client.exe %USERPROFILE%\Desktop
cd "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop"
client.exe
```

The first temporarily switches the current directory, so it is restored to what it was when run after `client.exe` terminates; the second makes a permanent switch to the desktop.

Comment: Worked like a charm! But quick question, what does `popd` do and why doesn't the console window close after execution? Can I remove it?

Comment: `pushd` saves the current directory on a stack and switches the current directory to the target given as its argument. `popd` removes the last-pushed directoryname from the stack and switches back to that. What happens after the `popd` I can't tell for certain - this may be a part-batch or may be the whole thing. If this is the whole thing, use the second version. The `pusd/popd` version is meant to temporarily change the current directory while `client` is run, then continue in the original directory. It should wait for `client` to terminate, then close. What is it doing/do you want it to do?

Comment: I already explained what I wanted but nevermind that, I just removed `popd` and it works perfectly as intended.

Answer (score 0):

If you want start an application and specify where files will be saved (Working Directory), use either

```
CD /D "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop"
"full_path_to_app\client.exe"
```

or

```
START "" /D"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop" "full_path_to_app\client.exe"
```

Copying the `.exe` file seems to be a needless action.

Comment: "Copying the .exe file seems to be a needless action" I specifically said I needed to copy it...